# Can't determine source of ng-change runtime error

Tags: angularjs

When I run the following code, I get a compile error during runtime but I can't seem to figure out what is wrong. The problem has to do with the way I'm using ng-change but I can't see what the problem is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js" ></script>
  </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

        $scope.main = {};

        $scope.doSomething = function()
        {
          var x = 1;
        };

        // No data
        $scope.main.test1 = [];

        // We have data!
        $scope.main.test2 = [{
            "some": "data"
        }];

    }]);

  </script>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
      <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <p>Test 1: {{ main.test1.length > 0 && 'My data' || 'No data' }}</p>
        <p>Test 2: {{ main.test2.length > 0 && 'My data' || 'No data' }}</p>
        <p>Test 3: {{ main.test2.length > 0 ? 'My data' : 'No data' }}</p>
        <div ng-init="scope = { isDisabled: true }">

        <input type="checkbox" ng-change="doSomething()"  />
        <button ng-disabled="{{scope.isDisabled}}">Disabled</button>
        <details open>
        <summary>Copyright 1999-2014.</summary>
        <p> - by Refsnes Data. All Rights Reserved.</p>
        <p>All content and graphics on this web site are the property of the company Refsnes Data.</p>
        </details>
</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

In jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/FS6z9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is right there in the error message...

> Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'ngChange', can't be
>   found!

You can't use `ng-change` on an element that doesn't have `ng-model`. It need something it can watch for changes and you've not given it anything to work on.

Comment: Discovered that too just a moment ago. Apparently by default input elements in Angular require an ng-model.